# global.html is unable to load NPAPI plugin from safari-extension builder but its loading from the direct link

Tags: macos, npapi, safari-extension

I am developing a Safari extension for both Mac and Win.
My extension is a trigger point for my plugin which i am storing at ** /Library/Internet Plug-ins/**
My extension's **global.html** is calling for my plugins mime type by an **object** tag

The issue is when on Mac, I load my extz through safari-extz-builder, the plugin is NOT getting called, but when I drag the same global.html to safari window, it is working. 
Also the same global.html is working fine on Windows.

I have repeated the same process with a generic plugin "npsimple" too which gave me same result (i.e. working on direct linking but failing on load from extension builder)

Code of my global.html:

```
<html>
    <body>        
 <object id="pluginobj" type="application/x-vnd-aplix-foo">Plugin FAILED to load</object>        
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function foo() {
   alert(document.getElementById("pluginobj").foo());
  }  
  foo();
 </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Link for npsimple:

http://git.webvm.net/?p=npsimple;a=tree

I must be missing something very stupid. 
Any ideas ??

TIA

Parimal Das

OSX 10.5.8 / Safari 5.0.3

Comment: Hey Did u get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found the same, and the only workaround I could come up with was to add the NPAPI plugin to a menu bar.  It works, but it seemingly shuts itself down for no reason and I have to reload it every time it does so.  Annoying.