# How can I load a NPAPI Plugin from a Safari extension?

Tags: npapi, safari-extension

My query is similar to this [global.html is unable to load NPAPI plugin from safari-extension builder but its loading from the direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519143/global-html-is-unable-to-load-npapi-plugin-from-safari-extension-builder-but-its).

How can I load a NPAPI Plugin from a Safari extension?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you can't. Unlike firefox and chrome extensions, Safari extensions don't allow you to embed npapi plugins in them.

Comment: Hi Taxilian,I have tried calling NPAPI Plugin from injected script of Safari extension,extension was loaded NPAPI successfully but it was failed loading from global.html,Thanks

Comment: of course it supports safari 5.1; if you have issues get the latest from source control. This isn't a good place to ask questions like that, however -- ask on the forums, the chat room, or the google group, rather than having discussions in the comments on SO

Answer (score 1):

You can create toolbar in Safari extension
Load npapi to the toolbar
On start extension make it invisible
Get toolbar object
Get plugin object from toolbar object

```
try {
    var toolbarWindow = safari.extension.bars[0].contentWindow;
    safari.extension.bars[0].hide();
    var doc = toolbarWindow.document;

    var plugin = doc.getElementById("plugin");
    if (plugin)
        plugin.samefunction();      
} catch(e) {
}
```

tested on Safari 5.1, 6.0